# HttpClient fails when running Angular application with Server-Side Rendering (Angular Universal)

Tags: angular, curl, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-httpclient

I have a [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) Rest-ful application running on port `8000`. I also have an Angular v14 application running locally on port `4200`. The Angular application communicates with the Rest-ful application via `HttpClient`.

The Angular application can run with `ng serve` (Client-Side Rendering, CSR) or `npm run dev:ssr` (Server-Side Rendering, SSR). When I run the Angular application via CSR or SSR using a browser everything is good (page renders, no errors in the browser console). However, when I issue a `curl` command using SSR I get errors.

```
curl http://localhost:4200
```

The error I see (as printed to the terminal) is as follows. This error message is not helpful as I have no idea if the problem is on the client or server side. A lot of posts indicates this is a CORS issue, but other articles suggest this type of error means the HTTP request did not even get executed.

```
HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map(0) {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/lucky',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/lucky: 0 Unknown Error',
  error: ProgressEvent {
    type: 'error',
    target: XMLHttpRequest {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    lengthComputable: false,
    loaded: 0,
    total: 0
  }
}
```

My FastAPI application is very simple. As you can see, I have enabled CORS and I basically have only 1 GET endpoint. This application is stored in a single file `main.py` and run in the terminal as `uvicorn main:app --reload`.

```
from random import randint

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
def read_root():
    return {'hello': 'world'}


@app.get('/lucky')
def get_lucky_number():
    return {
        'luckyNumber': randint(0, 10)
    }

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=['*'],
    allow_headers=['*']
)
```

The Angular application is also very simple. I use the following commands to create the application and add Angular Universal.

```
ng new web
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@14.2.0
```

I don't touch anything other than `app.component.html` and `app.component.ts`. For  the HTML, my code is as follows.

```
<h1>Hello, world</h1>
<h2>{{lucky.luckyNumber}}</h2>
<button (click)="nextNumber()">Next</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

For the TypeScript, my code is as follows.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface Lucky {
  luckyNumber: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  lucky: Lucky;

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
    this.lucky = {
      luckyNumber: -1
    }
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nextNumber();
  }

  nextNumber(): void {
    this.http.get<Lucky>('http://localhost:8000/lucky')
      .subscribe(
        r => this.lucky = r,
        e => console.error(e)
      )
  }
}
```

When I run the Angular application with CSR and issue a curl command, I get the following output. I see no errors reported in the terminal

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>
```

When I run the Angular application with SSR, and issue a curl command, I see the following output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></noscript><style ng-transition="serverApp">
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IiIsImZpbGUiOiJhcHAuY29tcG9uZW50LnNjc3MifQ== */</style></head>
<body>
  <app-root _nghost-sc17="" ng-version="14.2.12" ng-server-context="other"><h1 _ngcontent-sc17="">Hello, world</h1><h2 _ngcontent-sc17="">-1</h2><button _ngcontent-sc17="">Next</button><router-outlet _ngcontent-sc17=""></router-outlet><!--container--></app-root>
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

If you compare the CSR and SSR outputs, clearly, the SSR is rendering on the server but the HttpClient requests are failing (reported in terminal).

The FastAPI and Angular applications are not running in Docker containers; both are run from the terminal and manually as specified. CORS has been enabled with FastAPI.

Any idea on what's wrong?

You might ask, why are you testing with curl and not a browser? Well, I am testing with a browser too, and there is absolutely no issue with CSR or SSR. There is only an issue when I run Angular in SSR mode and use curl to test. I use curl to test because I want to see the fully rendered page as a crawler might (eg open graph `og` tags, SEO, meta tags).

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, in production, we almost certainly have to use the [SupplyData](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingOptions.cs#L42) hook because most live environments don't allow ajax calls back to the api during SSR

Comment: You are right. SSR does not have XHR object and that is the root cause of all of this issue. I am still searching for an answer since I am not using ASP.NET. Unfortunately, there is no documentation that I can find searching, though the documentation says NG Universal provides low-level objects for DOM and XHR (where's the code examples?). Their gitter page is dead and so I've been left searching still.

Comment: There's almost certainly a Python lib for fastapi/ssr. If it turns out not, you could check the code for ASP.NET Core which I linked

Comment: Yes, there is a library for FastAPI and SSR. I typically use FastAPI only for REST-ful endpoints and Angular for frontend. Obviously, this approach has setbacks as much as the approach for SSR. Angular Universal should do what it says (eg it specifically mentions SEO and tags for open graph), but there are no examples with XHR.

Comment: I did an attempt to [explain how ssr works for ASP.NET Core here](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-ssr-under-the-hood-asp-net-core-51562b70e511). The middleware launches `node` with the `entrypoint-http.js`. This script spawns an express server which invokes the bootmodule on demand. Each webrequest another webrequest is sent to this express server, and the result is returned to the client